# How to write a mongocxx query which have to retrieve the records between two time stamps?

Tags: c++, mongodb, mongo-cxx-driver

I'm trying transalate below mongodb query into mongocxx query.

```
db.collection.find({'order_id':'O1-0705','timestamp':{'$gte':new Date('2019-07-15 21:30:15.932'),'$lte':new Date('2019-07-15 21:35:15.932')}})
```

Facing error while converting timestamp as `bsoncxx::types::b_date` in the query.

This query is to get records with specific order id between given timestamps from a mongodb collection. I've tried getting the time as time_point and converting it as `bsoncxx::types::b_date`.

```
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point from_time = std::chrono::system_clock::now() + std::chrono::hours(5) + std::chrono::minutes(25);
        std::chrono::system_clock::time_point to_time = std::chrono::system_clock::now() + std::chrono::hours(5) + std::chrono::minutes(30);
    std::string order_id= "O1-0705";

mongocxx::cursor cursor = collection.find(
            document{} << "order_id" << order_id << "timestamp" << open_document << "$gte" << bsoncxx::types::b_date{ from_time } << "$lte" << bsoncxx::types::b_date{ to_time } << close_document << finalize);
```

Expected output: query should work without any error.

Actual output : getting below compile time errors.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2338   forcing MSVC stacktrace to show which T we're talking about.    MVController    d:\code\include\json\json.hpp   1550

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2338   could not find to_json() method in T's namespace    MVController    d:\code\include\json\json.hpp   1544

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2065   'force_msvc_stacktrace': undeclared identifier  MVController    d:\code\include\json\json.hpp   1550    

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2039   'force_msvc_stacktrace': is not a member of 'std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock,std::chrono::system_clock::duration>'    MVController    d:\code\include\json\json.hpp   1550
```

PS: the same code works without any error if the timestamp

```
mongocxx::cursor cursor = collection.find(
            document{} << "order_id" << order_id <<finalize);
```

I'm using MSVC 2017.

Comment: I tried your two queries and both compile correctly (using bsoncxx::builder::stream::document{} for the doc).

The compilation error you're getting points out to the `to_json()` method in
`include\json\json.hpp`
Are you by any chance calling the `to_json()` method around that code?

To print the docs retrieved you should use: `bsoncxx::to_json(doc)`

Comment: @SPM yes, i used that method but removed that line of code as soon as i saw that error.

Comment: then the errors now should not complain about the to_json() method anymore, right? Would you mind sharing a minimal, reproducible example and share the full error traces (with line numbers) please?